# Onblur and Onfocus in input field that can't be edited

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have an input field like this:

```
 <input class="" type="text" id="Name_11_1" name="Name" value="Your name:">
```

And want to change it  into this:

```
<input class="" type="text" id="Name_11_1" name="Name" value="Your name:" onblur="this.value = this.value || this.defaultValue;" onfocus="this.value == this.defaultValue && (this.value = '');"Your name:">
```

The problem is that I CAN'T edit the input field directly and have to use an external JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the existing event handlers and then attach your own:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('Name_11_1');

obj.removeAttribute('onfocus');
obj.removeAttribute('onblur');

obj.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    // your js code for blur event
});
obj.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    // your js code for focus event
});
```

Comment: I bet the problem was that you don't have jQuery included (?), so I changed my answer to a pure JS version.

Comment: sorry, I'm fully newbie...what I've to write in //your stuff?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#Name_11_1').blur(function() {
                $(this).val(YOUR_EXPR); 
            });

            $('#Name_11_1').focus(function() {
               $(this).val(YOUR_EXPR); 
             });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I write this but it doesn't work: <script>
$(function() {
    $('#Name_11_1').blur(function() {
      this.value = this.value || this.defaultValue;
    });

    $('#Name_11_1').focus(function() {
     this.value == this.defaultValue && (this.value = '');"Your name:";
     });
});
</script>

Comment: This didn't become $(this), $(this) just makes a jQuery wrapper for this :P.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser understands the `placeholder` attribute on `input` tags, you can use that:

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" placeholder="Your name">
```

You can then add JavaScript to provide a fallback for other browsers:

```
if (!'placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    $('#foo').on('focus', function() {
        // your code
    }).on('blur', function() {
        // your code
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: forgot that the OP can't edit the `input` tag directly. In that case, the code snippet can be modified to something like this:

```
var elem = $('#Name_11_1'),
    defaultValue = 'Your name';

if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    elem.attr('placeholder', defaultValue);
} else {
    elem.on('focus', function() {
        // your code
    }).on('blur', function() {
        // your code
    });
}
```

Comment: Problem is the OP wrote that he cannot edit the input, which probably means adding new attributes isn't possible either.

Comment: Yes, I know the placeholder tag, but I can't edit the entire input field. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops - updated answer to reflect the OP can't edit the input tag.